# Hover on image causes flickering and mouseout on nested div

Tags: jquery, hover, nested, flicker

I have a series of photos on a page, and when you hover over them, a white tinted effect fades in, and a title and description appear over it.

The problem I have is that if I hover over the text area, then the white tinted effect keeps fading out again. It's a strange flickering issue.

I need it to work so that regardless of where you hover on the image, it always stays tinted, and when however off it goes back to being just the normal image.

My code is below.

```
$('div.project-image a img').mouseover(function() {
    $('div.hover').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=70)');
            $('div.hover', $(this).parent().parent()).fadeIn(500);
});
    $('div.hover').mouseout(function() {
    $('div.hover').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=70)');
    $('div.hover', $(this).parent().parent()).fadeOut(500);
});
    $('div.hover').bind('click', function(e) {
    window.location = $(this).parent().children('a').attr('href');
```

});

The CSS styles used are:

```
#content div.project-image (styles the image area)
#content div.hover (displays the white tinted image)
#content div.hover h1 (styles the title)
#content div.hover p (styles the description)
```

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/ upload enough of the code needed to replicate the problem

Comment: I did try doing that, but I couldn't get it working. The code is spread across different bits of a wordpress theme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use "mouseEnter" and "mouseLeave" events instead. 
For pure javascript code those events are propietary and only listened correctly in IE.
But jquery normalizes them and makes them accesible in all browsers. 
They fire only once when you enter the parent element and not every time you hover on each child.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: wow, that just fixed it! Thank you. Can't believe it was that simple. So this is still fully query compatible and will not cause any issues?

Comment: No, you should experience any issues in any browsers. I use this events as default for my menus. I'm glad it was useful to you.